# $.get in AJAX Rails 4 not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, get

I've been using Rails for a couple of years, but this is the first time I've tried AJAX. I have a Rails 4 app. I'm just testing out functions right now. Ultimately I'd like to reload the partial on the app/views/stories/edit.html.erb page, but I can't get the $.get() function to do anything. Here's my app/assets/javascripts/story.js file:

```
$(document).on("page:change", function() {
  $.get('test.txt');
  timelyrefreshStories = function(){
    $.get('/signup');
  };
  setInterval(timelyrefreshStories, 8000);   
});
```

Where 'test.txt' is a file in my public folder & /signup is a route in my routes file.
This code does nothing. However when I change it to

```
$(document).on("page:change", function() {
  timelyrefreshStories = function(){
    location.reload(true);
  };
  setInterval(timelyrefreshStories, 8000);   
});
```

the entire page reloads, and the page reloads approximately every 8+ seconds - strangely, this happens for all pages on the site, not just the 'stories' pages. So I know that timelyrefreshStories is executing.

Also, I have:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

in my gemfile.
Any thoughts as to why $.get() doesn't do anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to tell jquery what to do when you get the request's response

```
$(document).on("page:change", function() {
  $.get('test.txt',function(response){
    /*do something here*/
  });
  timelyrefreshStories = function(){
    $.get('/signup',function(response){
      /*do something with this other response*/
    });
  };
  setInterval(timelyrefreshStories, 8000);   
});
```

I'm not sure what are you trying to do though, that javascript makes little sense to me

Comment: This code example wasn't meant to do anything but see if it executed.